# ASP.NET Core MVC - User Tables not being created when applying database migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sqlclient

I have an Asp.net Core MVC project and no user tables are being created in the database when I perform the commands:

```
Add-Migration migrationName

Update-Database
```

It'll update the tables my models are linked to, but will not add the user tables. This is an issue because i want to use the login feature provided by the ASP.NET Core MVC framework, and I thought these tables were supposed to populate the database automatically when applying a migration.

Does anyone know why this isn't happening automatically when updating my database through the nugget package manager console? This is a friend's project i got from github that i need to work on, and I'm not sure what to check for to make sure they have this project configured properly so that the user tables are created automatically.

How do I configure my project to add the user tables automatically?

Any help would be appreciated - I've looked at previous stack overflow answers but most are outdated.

**EDIT:** The Migration table in the DB does include the userTest migration i applied to the database. here is the migration file created in the MVC project as well, if that is helpful.:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace SEWebPage03.Migrations
{
    public partial class userTest : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the migration history table. Maybe Update-Database didn't recompile the migration? Check the source of the migration?

Comment: `Add-Migration` compares your current `context.Model` (after running `OnModelCreating`) against your previous `ModelSnapshot` (if any). If the generated migration is empty, then there was no difference between them? `Update-Database` tracks which migrations have been executed against this database, in a `__EFMigrationsHistory` database table.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks for the input. My migration table lists the userTest migration I applied to the project

Comment: I misread your question and thought you meant the migration history files in the MVC project (which seem rather empty, as I stated in the edit of my question) sorry about that. The migration history table does in fact list the migration userTest, though.

Comment: Does the project already have an empty migration? (eg did you friend reverse engineer a database, create a migration, then remove the up and down method bodies, since his database already existed).

Comment: in the most recent migration i performed, the file in the migration folder has the up and down bodies, there's just nothing in them. Is that what you are asking? I'm not sure how to check if they removed the up and down method bodies. Where do i check for that?

Comment: I believe that when you scaffolding the ASP.NET Core Identity models, it should generate some migration file. Or the file is somehow missing from the project. That means you don't do `add-migration` yourself for the User table which belongs to the ASP.NET Core Identity. If you do, an empty migration file may be generated (as for the migration `userTest` in your example). Here is purely my guess, you can try verifying it your own. Check the existence of ASP.NET Core Identity in your project, try re-scaffolding it ...

Answer (score 0):

If you selected `No Authentication` when the project was created...you will need to manually scaffold Identity Framework.
 This can be done...it takes several steps.

First would be to modify `ApplicationDbContext.cs`

Change this line

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext {}
```

To this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext {}
```

> You will need to install these Nuget packages.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI

Next Change StartUp.cs
Under `ConfigureServices`

add:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Use this for adding Roles

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI()
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Now scroll down a little further in StartUp.cs to the Configure method.

Before `app.UseAuthorization()` add `app.UseAuthentication();`

Important..it needs to be in this order.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now you add a new migration

> PM->add-migration scaffoldIdentity
>  PM->update-database

**Identity Migration**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace XXXXXXXXX.Migrations
{
    public partial class IdentityAdding : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the input so far! Unfortunately, I already have all of these added in my startup.cs file and in my ApplicationDBContext.cs. Even after having all these properties, the project isn't creating the user tables.

Comment: Any suggestion on how I can make the project "rescaffold" the tables somehow?

Comment: @izzyk I have a chat room if you need https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222344/efn

Comment: I think im just going to manually create the user tables by making a dummie project, and scripting the tables in SQL, then pasting the script for my new database. I have no history of the user tables being created, thats the problem... if I had history of them being created I wouldn't be asking the question.